# Spring Web Services 1.5.2 don't loggin exception to log file (backlog, spring boot 1.5.2)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j, logback, spring-ws

I have end point class:

```
@Endpoint
public class GetCustomerEndpoint {

    public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetCustomerEndpoint .class);


    @Transactional(value = "transactionManager", readOnly = true)
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = WebServiceConfig.NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCustomerRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCustomerResponse getCustomer(@RequestPayload GetCustomerRequest serviceRequest)
        throws ServerFaultException, ClientFaultException, Exception {

            throw new Exception("Exception to log file");
    }
```

But when exception throws it displays in client side:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">Exception to log file</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In log files or console is empty.
I want to see all exception in both place, and exception stack trace too.

In my log config:

```
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
```

Comment: Try adding another log config to GetCustomerEndpoint's package: logging.level.<package>=INFO

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new property to the config file to map the package you want to see the log, for example:

```
logging.level.<package>=INFO
```

Where  is the package, or the parent package of the class that's generating the log.
You can be more specific for some packages, like:

```
logging.level.com.test=INFO
logging.level.com.test.model=DEBUG
```

In this case, classes in the package **com.test** will show INFO logs and classes in **com.test.model** will show DEBUG logs.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Spring-Ws seems to not show any stacktrace exception on the log (I can't imagine why).

For me, this only works after register and setup a `SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver` bean. Per example:

```
@Bean
public SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver() {
    SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver();

    SoapFaultDefinition faultDefinition = new SoapFaultDefinition();
    faultDefinition.setFaultCode(SoapFaultDefinition.SERVER);
    exceptionResolver.setDefaultFault(faultDefinition);

    Properties errorMappings = new Properties();
    errorMappings.setProperty(Exception.class.getName(), SoapFaultDefinition.SERVER.toString());
    exceptionResolver.setExceptionMappings(errorMappings);
    exceptionResolver.setOrder(1);
    return exceptionResolver;
}
```